# How to activate Windows 2012 R2 Terminal License with command line

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, terminal-services

I have Installed **Remote Desktop Session Host** and **Remote Desktop Licensing**  services on Windows 2012 R2 Server which is working in WORKGROUP.

I have Enterprise Agreement Number for "Per user Cal Licensing". Normally I can make this activation using Remote Desktop Licensing Manager. But, I want to make this  activation via command line such as powershell or cmd..

I need to fill some fields such as company name, email, name surname, Enterprise Agreement Number etc..

Is there any way to make this or it is impossible via command line ??

I found this command ;

```
gwmi -namespace "Root/CIMV2/TerminalServices" Win32_TerminalServiceSetting
```

But, I could not found usage scenario for my case.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to import the module

```
Import-Module RemoteDesktopServices
```

Then you can use:

```
Set-RDLicenseConfiguration -LicenseServer license_server_name -Mode PerUser -ConnectionBroker connection_broker_name
```

Comment: I did not install Connection Broker. Do i need to install Connection Broker for this operation ?

Comment: Yes you have to do that. Please read [THIS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772245(v=ws.11).aspx)